# Pass unevaluated commands to a function in R

Tags: r, eval

I am a bit of an R novice, and I am stuck with what seems like a simple problem, yet touches pretty deep questions about how and when things get evaluated in R.

I am using Rserve quite a bit; the typical syntax to get things evaluated remotely is a bit of a pain to type repeatedly:

```
RSeval(connection, quote(try(command)))
```

So I would like a function r which does the same thing with just the call:

```
r(command)
```

My first, naive, bound to fail attempt involved:

```
r <- function(command) {
    RSeval(c, quote(try(command)))
}
```

You've guessed it: this sends, literally, `try(command)` to my confused Rserve daemon. I want `command` to be **partially** evaluated, if that makes any sense -- i.e. replaced by what I typed as an argument, but **without** evaluating it locally.

I looked for solutions to this, browsed throught the documentation for quote, substitute, eval, call, etc.. but I was not able to find something that worked. Either `command` gets evaluated locally, or not at all.

This is not a big problem, I can type the whole damn `quote(try())` thing all the time; but at this point I am mostly curious as to how to get this to work!

EDIT:
More explanations as to what I want to do.

- In the text above, `command` is meant to be a call do a function, ideally -- i.e., not a character string. Something like `a <- 3` or `assign("a", 3)` rather than `"a<-3"` or `quote(a<-3)`.
  I believe that this is part of what makes this tricky. It seems really hard to tell R not to evaluate this locally, but only send it literally. Basically I would like my function to be a bit like `quote()`, which does not evaluate its argument.
- Some explanation about my intentions. I wish to use Rserve frequently to pass commands to a remote R daemon. The commands would be my own (or my colleagues) and the daemon protected by firewall and authentication (and would not be run as root) -- so there is no worry of malicious commands being passed.
- To be perfectly honest, this is not a big issue, and I would be pretty happy to always use the `RSeval(c, quote(try()))`. At this point I see this more like an interesting inquiry into the subleties of R :-)

Comment: You might want to read my attempt to explain how to control evaluation in R and some of the pitfalls therein: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation

Comment: This link is now dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the substitute command, it can give you the argument unevaluated that you can build into the call.

Comment: You are right. I was sure I had try this before posting my question, but apparently not! This code does what I wanted:
    `r <- function(command) RSeval(c, substitute(command))`
Many thanks. It was simpler than I made it sound!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly - would `eval(parse(text = command))` do the trick? Notice that `command` is a character, so you can easily pass it as a function argument. **If** I'm getting the point...

Anyway, evaluating user-specified commands is potentially malicious, therefore not recommended. You should either install AppArmor and tweak it (which is not an easy one), or drop the whole evaluation thing...

Comment: Hi -- thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I think I was a bit unclear in my explanation. I will add an edit to the initial question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: `parse(text=command)` doesn't do the trick, as that would require `command` to be a character string. Unless I find a way to make `command` a character string without evaluating it; but neither `as.character` nor `deparse` seem to fit the bill.